# React Typescript: Wildcard Routes with BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

If I browse to `http://localhost:3000/confirm_email/` the route loads as expected but if I browse to `http://localhost:3000/confirm_email/h8s03kdbx73itls874yfhd` where `h8s03kdbx73itls874yfhd` is going to be diferent for each user I still want to load the /confirm_email route and I want to be able to get `h8s03kdbx73itls874yfhd` as a variable.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} from 'react-transition-group'
import {Layout} from "./components/layout";
import Home from './routes/home';
import Direction from './routes/direction';
import NotFound from './routes/not-found';


const Router: React.FC = () => {
  return (    
    <Context.Provider value={{ global, setGlobal }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Route render={({location}) => (
            <TransitionGroup>
              <CSSTransition timeout={450} classNames='fade' key={location.key}>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} />
                  <Route exact path = '/direction' component = {Direction} />
                  <Route exact path = '/confirm_email/:confirmationCode' component = {Confirm} />
                  <Route component = {NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
              </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
          )} />
          </Layout>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

the confirm_email then tries to log out the confirmation code

```
import React from "react";
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom';

interface MyProps {
  confirmationCode: string,
}

const Confirm: React.FC<MyProps & RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params.confirmationCode)
  return (
    <div className='page'>Confirm</div>
  );

} 

export default Confirm;
```

the error is 
`the error I get is Property 'confirmationCode' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Then it shouldn't be an `exact` match, and you should include a URL param.

Comment: so like? `<Route path = '/direction:id' component = {Direction} />` and then get it with `props.match.params.id`

Comment: adding or removing `exact` doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is Typescript dont know that your `confirmationCode` exists on RouteComponentProps. Rather if you look at the typing of `RouteComponentProps` you'll see that `match: match<Params>` which is defined default as an empty `{}`

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}
```

To fix the issue you would have to let typescript know that your custom param key exists on route params by explicitly passing your desired object to `RouteComponentProps`.

```
import React from "react";
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom';

interface MyProps {
  confirmationCode: string,
}

const Confirm: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<MyProps>> = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params.confirmationCode)
  return (
    <div className='page'>Confirm</div>
  );
} 

export default Confirm;
```

Alternatively you can be more declarative and use `type` for more cleaner syntax like:

```
interface MyProps {
  confirmationCode: string,
}

type MyRouteParams = RouteComponentProps<MyProps>;

const Confirm: React.FC<MyRouteParams> = (props) => {}
```

Comment: thank you, I was close I just didn't know to pass the object to RouteComponentProps